simplification for Word, Byte, Integers, and Memory
guys! I'm having a problem with understanding some concepts.
1-Why was it named 'word'?
2-What is the relationship between it and the integer size, what is the relation between the integer size and the device architecture? And why the (integer) specifically?
3-Why we use the term "byte", not "bit"? And why is the smallest unit for representing data is "byte", not "bit"?
I made some research, but I'm still confused. I'm a beginner, so advanced terms can be hard for me.
